# Python Latin Characters and Unicode

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, latin1, python-unicode

I have a tree structure in which keywords may contain some latin characters.  I have a function which loops through all leaves of the tree and adds each keyword to a list under certain conditions.

Here is the code I have for adding these keywords to the list:

```
print "Adding: " + self.keyword
leaf_list.append(self.keyword)
print leaf_list
```

If the keyword in this case is `université`, then my output is:

```
Adding: université
['universit\xc3\xa9']
```

It appears that the print function properly shows the latin character, but when I add it to the list, it gets decoded.

How can I change this?  I need to be able to print the list with the standard latin characters, not the decoded version of them.

Comment: Your **terminal** knows how to interpret UTF-8. The string contents is just (decoded) bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have unicode objects, but byte strings with UTF-8 encoded text. Printing such byte strings to your terminal *may* work if your terminal is configured to handle UTF-8 text.

When converting a list to string, the list contents are shown as *representations*; the result of the `repr()` function. The representation of a string object uses escape codes for any bytes outside of the printable ASCII range; newlines are replaced by `\n` for example. Your UTF-8 bytes are represented by `\xhh` escape sequences.

If you were using Unicode objects, the representation would use `\xhh` escapes *still*, but for Unicode codepoints in the Latin-1 range (outside ASCII) only (the rest are shown with `\uhhhh` and `\Uhhhhhhhh` escapes depending on their codepoint); when printing Python automatically encodes such values to the correct encoding for your terminal:

```
>>> u'université'
u'universit\xe9'
>>> len(u'université')
10
>>> print u'université'
université
```

Compare this to byte strings:

```
>>> 'université'
'universit\xc3\xa9'
>>> len('université')
11
>>> 'université'.decode('utf8')
u'universit\xe9'
>>> print 'université'
université
```

Note that the length reflects that the `é` codepoint is encoded to two bytes as well. It was my terminal that presented Python with the `\xc3\xa9` bytes when pasting the `é` character into the Python session, by the way, as it is configured to use UTF-8, and Python has detected this and decoded the bytes when I defined a `u'..'` Unicode object literal.

I strongly recommend you read the following articles to understand how Python handles Unicode, and what the difference is between Unicode text and encoded byte strings:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder

Answer (score 0):

When you print a list, you get the `repr` of the items it contains, which for strings is different from their contents:

```
>>> a = ['foo', 'bär']
>>> print(a[0])
foo
>>> print(repr(a[0]))
'foo'
>>> print(a[1])
bär
>>> print(repr(a[1]))
'b\xc3\xa4r'
```

The output of `repr` is supposed to be programmer-friendly, not user-friendly, hence the quotes and the hex codes. To print a list in a user-friendly way, write your own loop. E.g.

```
>>> print '[', ', '.join(a), ']'
[ foo, bär ]
```