# Print python unicode list of strings on on mac console

Tags: python, macos, unicode

I am on Mac OS terminal console running Python 2.7

```
>>> print 'One' # Nice
One
>>> print 'Один' # Unicode strings prints just fine also
Один
>>> print ['One', 'Two'] # List of ascii strings prints just fine
['One', 'Two']
>>> print ['Один', 'Два'] # List of unicode strings prints with codes
['\xd0\x9e\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbd', '\xd0\x94\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0']
```

How can I avoid getting unicode escape sequences and just get following as an output for the last command?

```
>>> print ['One', 'Two'] # How can I get this??
[u'Один', u'Два']
```

I know, I can run a cycle through the list, but in reality my structure is much more complex, so I need a lean command to print the entire structure without encoding letters.

I need this for debugging of complicated data structures. When strings are in escape codes - they are totally unreadable. Is there any library/function which is capable to print without encoding. My console seems to be able to display such characters just fine.

Comment: You don't have Unicode. You have *UTF-8 bytes*. You cannot get what you want even when you decode those values from UTF-8 because lists like all containers show representations, not the values directly.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745876/python-print-unicode-list) might have some helpful ideas, since it also deals with Unicode strings *inside lists* (thus, with the added twist of `repr()`).  Note that explanation of the accepted answer is severely lacking -- you should review the explanation and references in [the previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220245/python-latin-characters-and-unicode).

Comment: I have seen [both](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745876/python-print-unicode-list) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220245/python-latin-characters-and-unicode)  befre I asked this one. I do not see what I want there...

Comment: It talks about the same subject, but did not provide the answer. So I would appreciate if you either answer my question directly, or unmark this question as duplicate and let others help me. Thanks.